# String come first than number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string, date

I've got this code :

```
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="float-left">
                                <!-- {{selectedTemplat?.modifiedAt | date:'d-LLL-yyyy'}} -->
                                27 / sep / 2023
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

And the output it's come like this! :
[image]

Any suggestions to show it like this : 27 / sep / 2023

Comment: Docs? https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options

Comment: Thanks Kapobajza, Maybe because the website format is rlt!

Answer (score 1):

You can use datePipe like this. According to official docs: `dd/MMM/yyyy`
Example:

```
{{ dateObj | date:'dd/MMM/yyyy' }}
```

See Docs as well: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe